# Mapbox Studio uploaded mbtiles broken?

Tags: qgis, mapbox, mbtiles, mapbox-studio

Using the QGIS "Generate XYZ Tiles (mbtiles)" tool I created an mbtile tileset. My input source was a 3-band RGB raster with CRS: `EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected`. I used minimum zoom of 1 and maximum zoom of 7.

Upon uploading to Mapbox my tileset ended up looking like this at zoom: 3.24
[image]

After zooming to 3.53:
[image]

Upon zooming the tileset I uploaded it becomes misaligned with the basemap and I end up with some disjoint tiles too. What is causing the tileset to "shift" projection at this zoom and return hanging tile?

Doug

*Update 1*

I ran the same operation again, XYZ in QGIS and upload to Mapbox Studio, same issue. However, on a smaller dataset I did not experience the same issue after going through the same process. I'm befuddled.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue related to the extents input for the QGIS "Generate XYZ Tiles (mbtiles)" tool. I was using the "Calculate from layer" option to populate the extents. However, those extents were beyond the defined `EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected` extents. So, after reigning in the extent bounds and re-running, the uploaded mbtiles looked great.

**Solution:**

Don't allow the extents to exceed the projections bounding box when using the QGIS "Generate XYZ Tiles (mbtiles)" tool.